# Functionality of html5 matrix transform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, matrix

I'm currently trying to get an understanding of how to do matrix transformations when drawing objects in html5 but the differing explanations found in multiple different sources of information has caused some confusion. I've found information saying that in order to animate drawn objects in html5 as seen [here](http://devhammer.net/blog/exploring-html5-canvas-part-1---introduction/) while I've also seen that transformations can be applied to individual objects on the page by transforming a drawn point, but I'm not really sure how it works.

I've found a code sample that implements an animation of legs (two lines) but it does the animation without applying transformations to the canvas, using a function object for the transformation matrix  defined in some other file. The code provides its own implementation of `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` (which are normally used with the canvas object) in which it transforms a point passed in, readjusts its position based on the viewport, and then calls the canvas' version of move to passing in the transformed point.

So there are a few points of confusion here:
1. What is the purpose of implementing a new transform function on the transformation  matrix object when setTransform() can just be used on the canvas?
2. Methods like `rotate()` and `translate()` are called on the matrix object without having the point passed in so how are any of these operations actually applied?
3. When should transformations be applied to the entire canvas (as done in the link provided) as opposed to on specific objects drawn as it seems that both can work?

I generally am just looking for a general overview of this as I'm rather confused about how this works. The code from the example is below for reference:

```
<head>
<script src=g.js></script>
<script src=matrix4x4.js></script>
</head>
<body onload=g_start()>
<canvas id=myCanvas1 width=480 height=480></canvas>
<script>
   var w, h, g;

   function viewport(p) {
      return [ w/2 * p[0] + w/2, h/2 - p[1] * w/2 ];
   }

   function moveTo(p) {
      var q = m.transform(p);  // APPLY 3D MATRIX TRANFORMATION
      var xy = viewport(q);    // APPLY VIEWPORT TRANSFORM
      g.moveTo(xy[0], xy[1]);
   }

   function lineTo(p) {
      var q = m.transform(p);  // APPLY 3D MATRIX TRANFORMATION
      var xy = viewport(q);    // APPLY VIEWPORT TRANSFORM
      g.lineTo(xy[0], xy[1]);
   }

   myCanvas1.animate = function(_g) {
      g = _g;
      w = g.canvas.width;
      h = g.canvas.height;

      g.fillStyle = 'rgb(200,140,255)';
      g.beginPath();
      g.moveTo(0, 0);
      g.lineTo(w, 0);
      g.lineTo(w, h);
      g.lineTo(0, h);
      g.lineTo(0, 0);
      g.stroke();

      g.fillStyle = 'rgb(128,0,0)';
      g.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';

      var legBend = .4;

      var t = 3 * time;

      for (var leg = 0 ; leg < 2 ; leg++) {
     var angle = -Math.PI/2 * (1 + Math.sin(time));
     console.log(angle);
         var sign = (leg == 0) == (angle < -Math.PI/2) ? -1 : 1;

         m.identity();
         m.rotateY(-Math.PI/2 * (1 + Math.sin(time)));

         g.beginPath();

         m.translate(0, .5, .1 * sign);
         moveTo([0,0,0]);             // HIP

         m.rotateZ(-.5 * legBend + sign * legBend * Math.cos(t));

         m.translate(0, -.5, 0);

         lineTo([0,0,0]);             // HIP

         m.rotateZ(2 * legBend + 2 * legBend * sign * Math.sin(t));
         m.translate(0, -.5, 0);
         lineTo([0,0,0]);             // KNEE

         m.translate(-.1, 0, 0);
         lineTo([0,0,0]);             // KNEE

         g.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
         g.lineWidth = 30;
         g.stroke();

         g.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
         g.lineWidth = 20;
         g.stroke();
      }
   }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It physically pains me to not see quotes around `src=g.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important html5 canvas transformation concepts:**

- All canvas transformation methods (as well as `.transform`) operate relative to the current canvas origin and that origin is given coordinate [0,0]. The starting origin is at the top-left of the canvas. `.setTransform` will both reset the current canvas origin and then make transformations relative to that reset origin.
- Transformations **do not affect** existing drawings. So fillRect(0,0) followed by translate(5,0) will not move the already drawn rect. The existing rect will still display at the top-left of the canvas.
- Transformations **do affect** new drawings.
- The `translate` method will move the origin by the specified x,y distances. So translate(5,0) will cause the canvas drawing origin [0,0] to be 5 pixels from the left side of the canvas. So translate(5,0) followed by fillRect(0,0) will cause the new rect to display 5 pixels from the left side of the canvas.
- Transformations actually translate (move), rotate, scale the entire canvas drawing surface. So new drawings are not individually moved, rotated or scaled. *New drawing appear moved, rotated or scaled because the whole canvas drawing surface has been moved, rotated or scaled.*
- Transformation are cumulative. So if you translate(5,0) and then translate(0,50) the canvas origin [0,0] will be at 5 pixels from the left and 50 pixels from the top. So fillRect(0,0) will be drawn 5 pixels from the left and 50 pixels from the top.

**So, to answer your questions:**

1. Sequential transformations are useful because transformations are cumulative. So to make a person image "move" you can use the cumulative effects of transformations without having to remember their last position or having to calculate their new position.

   ```
   // the person image will move across the canvas in 5px increments over time
   // No need to remember its last location
   // No need to calculate its new position
   // That's because the canvas internally remembers & calculates its own origin.
   for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
       context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
       context.translate(5,0);
       context.drawImage(person,0,0);
       // wait 1 second
   }
   ```
2. Since all transformations are relative to the current canvas origin coordinate, you don't have to re-specify that coordinate for any transformation method -- the canvas "remembers" its current origin for you.
3. Individual canvas drawings are not affected by transformations. Transformations move the whole canvas and new drawings just "go along for the ride". Any drawings that existed before the transformations are not affected at all by those subsequent transformations -- pre-existing drawings remain exactly where they were first drawn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you're saying that any time you're doing transformations in html5, you can only apply the transformations to the entire canvas and not to specific objects (i.e. without using ```setTransform()```)? It just seemed to me that in the example, the ```transform()``` function might be applying its own kind of transformation that doesn't use ```setTransform()``` because that function only works with 2D lines while this program is working with 3d.

Comment: Also, if using ```setTransform()``` is the only way to implement a ```Transform()``` method, how could you use it with 3d shapes, b/c I'm currently using jquery to get the context with ```canvas.getContext("2d")``` but I don't know if there is a way to do this in 3d.